# Builder with lambda expression for Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, builder, lombok

I have two class with me as mentioned below.
I wanted to create two instances of **`class A`**.

I want to create instance obj2 from existing instance obj1 with updated value of a3 attribute as **`"Java"`**.

I had tried below line using **Builder**, but it's not working.

```
A obj2 = obj1.builder().a3("Java").build();
```

I am able to do it with calling constructor, but I wanted to do it **`Builder`** pattern only.

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Data
class A {
    String a1;
    String a2;
    String a3;
    B b;

    A(String b1, String b2, String b3, B b) {
        this.a1 = b1;
        this.a2 = b2;
        this.a3 = b3;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

@Builder
@Data
class B {
    String b1;
    String b2;
    String b3;

    B(String b1, String b2, String b3) {
        this.b1 = b1;
        this.b2 = b2;
        this.b3 = b3;
    }

}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        B b = new B("a", "b", "b");
        A obj1 = new A("a1", "b1", "b1", b);
        A obj2 = new A("x1", "y1", "z1", b);
        List<A> list= new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(obj1);
        list.add(obj2);
        list.forEach(a -> {
            a.toBuilder().a1("newA1").a2("newA2").build();
            repository.save(a);
        });

        A obj3 = obj1.toBuilder().a3("Java").build();
    }
}
```

As mentioned in updated code , i have list of A with me, and i want to update **`a1 and a2`** attributes of all element in list using builder. But builder is not working fine with lambda.
If i will use setter with below code it's working fine.

```
list.forEach(a -> {
    a.setA1("newA1");
    a.setA2("newA2");
});
```

I am not able to get updated values for **`a1 and a2`** in case of **`Builder`** with **`Lambda`**

Comment: Creating an updated version of an existing object is simply not a use case for `Builder`. There is an experimental `Wither` you can use for this purpose.

Comment: It turns out `Wither` was renamed to `With` and moved out of experimental in Lombok 1.18.10: [`With`](https://www.projectlombok.org/features/With).

Comment: @DavidConrad it is a use-case, and Lombok has support for it.

Comment: @Michael I forgot about `toBuilder` because I never use it, myself. I've upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This statement doesn't do anything

```
list.forEach(a -> {
    a.toBuilder().a1("newA1").a2("newA2").build();  //<<<
    repository.save(a);
});
```

You are creating a new object from the old one and then throwing it away. It will not make changes to the existing object. Consider

```
list.stream()
    .map(a -> a.toBuilder().a1("newA1").a2("newA2").build())
    .forEach(repository::save);
```

Comment: i had already enable it.
Even in normally while updating value with same approach is working fine.
But when i am using with lambda expression its not working.

Comment: @SagarGangwal How are we supposed to solve your problem if the code that you show us does not represent the problem?

Comment: I had added exact code, and also mentioned working approach of same.

Comment: @SagarGangwal It's not the exact code, because your code didn't have `(toBuilder = true)`. Anyway, updated my answer

Comment: I had added my updated code, and also regarding braces i have multiple task need to perform after setting updated value. And finally need to save in Database.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by user @Michael already fixed a bunch of your errors in the paste.

The reason "it is not working" (please be more specific next time) is that you are doing a no-op.

The operation:

`x.toBuilder().changeSomething().build()` **makes a new object**. It does not modify the object: Builder is for immutables; you can't modify them.

So, for each element in the list, you are deriving a builder from it, making some modifications, creating a new object out of that, and then promptly tossing this object in the garbage.

try:

```
list.stream().map(a -> a.toBuilder().a1("newA1").build()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or the much simpler to follow:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    var withNewValue = list.get(i).toBuilder().a1("newA1").build();
    list.set(i, withNewValue);
}
```

sometimes the old ways are the best ways.